# Deploying a Python Program with External imports, written in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm new with Python. I started using PyCharm and it is a great IDE, everything works fine when I work in it.
But there is one problem. 
I need to use external modules in my project. In this case, requests and pyodbc.
I installed them within the IDE and there were no problem. But the program has to work on server, not in my IDE. So, how do I "deploy" a program so that all the imported modules are included? Do I have to search for them individually and just copy them with the source file?

Comment: what kind of "server" do you have? On debian linux you could use PIP to install need packages e.g. `pip install pyodbc` or just create a python package of your program and mention required dependencies. In any case "just copy" is not the correct way, because you won't get updates.

Comment: I have a windows server.
How do I create a python package? I mean, the PyCharm just installs them in its library and I have to only write "import SomeModule" at the start.
When I move the program written this way to another device,  what do I have to change in it?